# VB.Net embedded Flash Object creates problems

Tags: vb.net, flash, interop, embed

Ì have had this problem in a number of projects and I have almost given up.  I am sure there is a solution though.  When I insert a Flash object in a VB.Net Windows Forms application, it works fine for a little while and then I see this error in the Design Screen. I am using Visual Studio 2010

**Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I have read several descriptions of why this happens, and apparently it has something to do with strong naming (or lack thereof), but have not found a solution yet. I used Add Reference->COM->Shockwave Flash (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\Flash32_11_2_202_235.ocx) If I ignore the error it appears to work fine, but I don't want my users to have a problem.

I know I can use a browser control and play the Flash in that, but for reasons I won't get into, I have to use a Flash control.  Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I can't promise this to work for you, but it worked for me.
First, you have to locate a file on your computer titled AxImp.exe. You have to run it from the command prompt. This file is located (for me at least) here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\x64

Once you do find and run it, you have to point it to the correct Flash.ocx file you're using, like so:

```
AxImp.exe <path>\Flash.ocx
```

Once you've done that you should end up with 2 DLL files in the same directory as the .ocx file. One called AxShockwaveFlashObjects.dll and another called ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll.

You don't care about ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll, just AxShockwaveFlashObjects.dll.
Grab that file and the Flash*.ocx file and paste them into the project directory.
Then include them into your references. This should open up two new references, AxShockwaveObjects and ShockwaveObjects.
Make sure you're Using both of them.
After this, you have to register the Flash*.ocx using RegSvr32 from your command prompt (make sure to run CMD in admin mode). That is done like so:

```
C:\RegSvr32 <path>\Flash.ocx
```

This worked for me. I was having the exact same problem (which is what led me here). It could be a half backed hack workaround but for now, that's how it worked for me.

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Hope it goes well for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I had this issue yesterday and the solution, at least in my case, was very simple. All I had to do was to change the Platform and Platform Target to x86 (Build tab of project property).